Is there a good reason to expect $\pi^2$ here?
I was playing around with generalized hypergeometric functions in Wolfram Mathematica and noticed that:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
{}_{3} F_2\left(\begin{matrix}1 ~~~ 1 ~~~ 1 ~~~\\\frac32 ~~~ 2\end{matrix} \middle|1 \right)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\\
{}_{3} F_2\left(\begin{matrix}1 ~~~ 1 ~~~ 1 ~~~\\2 ~~~ 2\end{matrix} \middle|1 \right)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\\
{}_{3} F_2\left(\begin{matrix}\frac12 ~~~ \frac12 ~~~ 1 ~~~\\\frac32 ~~~ \frac32\end{matrix} \middle|1 \right)=\frac{\pi^2}{8}
\end{eqnarray} $$
This was surprising! We can obviously convert the functions back to their sums and prove those equalities by themselves (for example, the second case is just the definition of $\zeta(2)$ rewritten in hypergeometric form) but is there a deeper reason for why these results are true? Does there exist a hypergeometric transformation which makes this something to be expected?
I have looked here and couldn't find anything applicable, is this really a coincidence?

You'll probably find them if you look more closely at the Hypergeometric3F2 list of identities for $z=1$. Your first expression is a case of this identity, for example.

This is a very interesting identity! But I really want to know if they are directly related, via some kind of ${}_3 F_2$ to ${}_3 F_2$ transformation, or if they are, in a sense, coincidences, like your identity seems to suggest
